# No events received when using DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource() to monitor changes to file

Tags: swift, filesystems

I found [this article about watching for changes](https://swiftrocks.com/dispatchsource-detecting-changes-in-files-and-folders-in-swift) and I've tried to follow along properly. My dispatch source gets created, but I never receive any events.

To make sure I was getting anything and everything, I made sure to set the `eventMask = .all`.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()

    Task {
        self.configurl = await self.openfile(forkey: self.keybookmarkconfig)
                    
        if let url = self.configurl {
    
            print("creating filehandle for \(url.absoluteString)")
            self.configfilehandle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: url)
    
            print("creating dispatch source to watch \(url.absoluteString)")
            self.source = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(
                fileDescriptor: self.configfilehandle.fileDescriptor,
                eventMask: .all,
                queue: DispatchQueue.main
            )
    
            print("setting event handler for dispatch source")
            self.source.setEventHandler {
                print("config file changed")
            }
    
            print("done with watcher setup")
    
        }

        
    }
    
}
```

I tried updating the file in numerous ways. I edited/saved it in BBEdit and TextEdit, but because of the warning about how those types of editors might delete/recreate the file, also I tried editing it from the command line with vim. I even did `echo "test" >> myfile.txt`. But I never received any events in my event handler. I restarted my app in between each of these tests, so I had a fresh file handle.

Any idea why I'm not receiving any event callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the dispatch source has been created, you have to call `self.source.activate()` so that the source gets scheduled and started. Otherwise it's just sitting there.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsource/2300040-makefilesystemobjectsource):

> After creating the dispatch source, use the methods of the DispatchSourceProtocol protocol to install the event handlers you need. The returned dispatch source is in the inactive state initially. When you are ready to begin processing events, call its activate() method.

Comment: Thank you so much, every single example of this function is missing that call to activate and I didn't see that in the discussion section.

Comment: Bad things happened and I lost this code last year. I sat down to recreate it this week and ran face first into this problem again and after hours of struggling finally found my own question again and this answer again which solved the whole problem. /facepalm and /woo